# Remove intermediate View Controllers from Navigation Stack - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

I have a navigation stack as following:

VcA -> VcB -> VcC

When I press the back button on VcC navigationBar, I want to go to VcA.

I tried doing `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]` but it first pops to VcB and then goes to VcA.

I also tried this:

```
NSMutableArray *navigationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[navigationArray removeObjectAtIndex: 1]; 
self.navigationController.viewControllers = navigationArray;
```

But it doesn't work. It still shows VcB first then shows VcA.

I tried both of the above code in `viewWillDisappear` of VcC.

Please help how can I solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: `viewWillDisappear` is too late. You should use your second block of code in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks man! That's it! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewWillDisappear` is too late to manipulate the view controller stack; the transition to view controller B is already underway. You should modify the stack using your second block of code in `viewDidAppear` so that when the back button is tapped the navigation controller transitions back to view controller A

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
    {
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[nameOfYourViewControllerYouWantToNavigate class]])
        {
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];

            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done by:

**1. Getting an array of all controllers present in stack**

```
NSArray *controllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
```

**2. Then telling the navigation controller to pop to a controller at a specific index (e.g. 0):**

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[controllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try pop to root without animation,
 i.e [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO] –